# Code analysis error CA1804 happening intermittently

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I am getting the following error intermittently:

> CA1804 : Microsoft.Performance : 'ChannelFactoryCache.GetChannel(string)' declares a variable, '<>s__LockTaken0', of type 'bool', which is never used or is only assigned to. Use this variable or remove it

for the following code in the first `if` statement

```
public static T GetChannel<T>(string endpoint)
{
    if (!Cache.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        lock (ObjLock)
        {
            if (!Cache.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(endpoint);
                channelFactory.Open();
                Cache.Add(typeof(T), channelFactory);
            }
        }
    }

    T channel = ((ChannelFactory<T>)Cache[typeof(T)]).CreateChannel();
    ((IChannel)channel).Open();
    return channel;
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The CA is done in release mode.

Comment: What versions of .NET and Visual Studio are involved here?

Comment: Are you also using Code Contracts? I once saw an issue like this with an older version of Code Contracts.

Comment: No, I am not using Code Contracts.

Comment: This is Visual Studio 2010 SP1 building .Net 4.0 application.